# Error sending form fields through jquery ajax

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter

I am having a problem sending the dataString to the server. Aparently it is not pulling the values correctly from the form. Below is my jquery and my php.

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
    $("#submitForm").live('click', function() {
        updateUserInfo();
    });

var birthdate = $("#birthdate");
var sex = $("#sex");
var interestedIn = $("#interestedIn");
var relationshipStatus = $("#relationshipStatus");
var knownLanguages = $("#knownLanguages");
var religiousViews = $("#religiousViews");
var politicalViews = $("#politicalViews");
var aboutMe = $("#aboutMe");
var mobilePhone = $("#mobilePhone");
var neighborhood = $("#neighborhood");
var website = $("#website");
var email = $("#email");

var dataString = birthdate + sex + interestedIn + relationshipStatus + knownLanguages + politicalViews + aboutMe + mobilePhone + neighborhood + website + email;

function updateUserInfo() {
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "JSON",
        url: "<?=base_url()?>index.php/regUserDash/updateUserInfo",
        data: dataString,
        json: {userInfoUpdated: true},
        success: function(data) {
        if(data.userInfoUpdated == true) {
            alert("hello");
        }
      }
   });
}
});
```

My PHP:

```
 public function updateUserInfo() {
        $userid = $this->session->userdata('userid');
        $birthdate = $this->input->post("birthdate");
        $sex = $this->input->post("sex");
        $interestedIn = $this->input->post("interestedIn");
        $relationshipStatus = $this->input->post("relationshipStatus");
        $languages = $this->input->post("languages");
        $religiousViews = $this->input->post("religiousViews");
        $politicalViews = $this->input->post("politicalViews");
        $aboutMe = $this->input->post("aboutMe");
        $mobilePhone = $this->input->post("mobilePhone");
        $neighborhood = $this->input->post("neighborhood");
        $websites = $this->input->post("websites");
        $email = $this->input->post("email");

        $this->db->query("INSERT IGNORE INTO user_info (birthdate, sex, interestedIn, relationshipStatus, Languages, religiousViews, politicalViews, aboutMe, mobilePhone, neighborhood, websites, email, userid)
                          VALUES('{$birthdate}', '{$sex}', {$relationshipStatus}', '{$languages}, {$religiousViews}', '{$politicalViews}', {$aboutMe}', '{$mobilePhone}' {$neighborhood}', '{$websites}', {$email}', '{$userid}')");

        echo json_encode(array('userInfoUpdated' => true));
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) to get the value of the element.
And change your `dataString` to:

```
var dataString = {'birthdate' : birthdate, 'sex' : sex, 'interestedIn' : interestedIn, 'relationshipStatus' : relationshipStatus, 'knownLanguages' : knownLanguages, 'politicalViews' : politicalViews, 'aboutMe' : aboutMe, 'mobilePhone' : mobilePhone, 'neighborhood' : neighborhood, 'website' : website, 'email' : email};
```

From [api.jquery.com](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/):
[image: jQuery.ajax data]

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, but it is still not working. Here is my error: http://i50.tinypic.com/2bp750.png. If you notice it isn't even passing through json.

Comment: Everything is running correctly. This is odd. here is my PHP if that might help any: http://pastebin.com/R7tjfkDx.

Comment: @MichaelGrigsby check *Network* tab in Chrome and look for the request which JQuery sends. Is it there? If yes, look through request headers and find *Form data*. What is there?

Comment: Only the default values from the select boxes are being passed

Comment: @MichaelGrigsby Got it, select boxes, thats what causing the problem. E.g. `$('#sex')` is a select box, and to obtain selected value you should use [:selected](http://api.jquery.com/selected-selector/). `var sex = $('#sex :selected').val()`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15142/discussion-between-hookman-and-michael-grigsby)

Comment: Okay. Thanks man. Give me a little while. I'm not sitting in front of my computer at this moment.

Answer (score 0):

The code `$("#birthdate");` will return an element with id #birthdate but not it's value. use val function to get the value in it. like `var birthdate = $("#birthdate").val();`